# How to bind popup user control to view model and how to handle back button? (Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime)

Tags: mvvm, binding, user-controls, windows-runtime, back-button

I'm working on WP 8.1 runtime application and I'm using Caliburn.Micro. Application follows MVVM pattern. I have an ItemPageView and ItemPageViewModel and data binding works as it should.

I want to add popup (UserControl) over ItemPageView(Page) after I click one item on ItemPage. Popup has only one ScrollViewer containg one Image and I want to do something like this :

```
<Image x:Name="imageFull" 
       Source="{Binding _currentItem.ImageURL}"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

_currentItem is a property of ItemPageViewModel.

My second problem is related to Back button. I've added this to my code:

```
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender,  Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (_popUpActive)
        {
            _popUpActive = false;
            _showImagePopUp.Close();
            frame.GoForward();
            //var lastPage = frame.BackStack.LastOrDefault();
            //frame.Navigate(typeof(SingleGuideView));
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

After I click on Back button Popup will close, and after that, it will navigate back. Only "solution" to stay on current view is to call frame.GoForward(); .

Answer (score 0):

About the Popup, you can write some Code like the following in you XAML (Keep the Popup in just below the First Grid):

```
<!-- This is the First Grid -->
<Grid>
    <Popup x:Name="myPopup" Width="400">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image x:Name="imageFull" 
                   Source="{Binding _currentItem.ImageURL}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

You can handle the problem with the Popup by having a Counter for the Hardware Back Button Press. Have a look at the Code Below:

```
int _popUpCounter = 0, _dummyCounter = 0;
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender,  Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    _dummyCounter++;
    Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (_popUpCounter == 0 && _dummyCounter == 1)
    {
        _popUpCounter = 1;
        _popUpActive = false;
        _showImagePopUp.Close();
        frame.GoForward();
        //var lastPage = frame.BackStack.LastOrDefault();
        //frame.Navigate(typeof(SingleGuideView));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (_popUpCounter == 1 && _dummyCounter == 2)
    {
        _popUpCounter = _dummyCounter = 0;
        frame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This will help you with the problem related to Popup.

Comment: Tank you for your effort.
Unfortunately, back button still works the same(I'me setting _popUpCounter = (_popUpActive)?1:0;)

Also, I think we misunderstood. My popup is actually User Control in a seperate XAML file. So, every time I navigate to ItemPage, my User Control also initializes. When i click on a certain item, my View Model actives popup. Do I need to set Data Context or somethig like that?